# Error coming on the Local Server while logging in the Python and Django Application

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I want my login.html page to hit first as a landing page in my Python and Django application. But an error is showing in urls.py file of the project on the server as soon as I am hitting the enter button after filling the username and password.

URLS.py File of the Project:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('tabs_app.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

VIEWS.py file of the app in the project where index.html file is located:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def login(request):
    return render(request, 'login.html')
```

URLS.py file of the app in the project where index.html file is located:

```py
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.login, name='login')
]
```

VIEWS.py file of the app in which LOGIN code is written:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

# Create your views here.

def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        if user is not None:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')

        else:
            messages.info(request, 'invalid credentials')
            return redirect('login')

    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

URLS.py file of the app where LOGIN code is written:

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('login', views.login, name='login')
]
```

ERROR MESSAGE which is coming on the local server:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Using the URLconf defined in tabs_pilot.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. [name='login']
2. admin/
3. accounts/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, login, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to use Django's build in login functionality? In this case your endpoint is http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login and your template should be found within the registration directory in your templates directory.

Mozilla does a pretty good job of outlining how this all works in their Django Tutorial. Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication).

Comment: Yes, you are right. The login file is inside ACCOUNTS folder which is not fetching properly @aust1n

Comment: @Dipanshu So did I answer your question? Or are you still seeking more guidance. Please accept my solution if it solved it.

Comment: Hi @aust1n, thanks for the answer that you have given, from the solution provided I am able to redirect the login page as a landing page but after submitting the details, it is throwing the same error:

Using the URLconf defined in tabs_pilot.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
1. [name='login']
2. admin/
3. accounts/
^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The current path, login, didn't match any of these.